# Gamedev's Winterbash 2020 Showcase! [proposal]

Tags: discussion, event

**The event post is [here](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2868/gamedevs-winterbash-2020-showcase). Thanks for the feedback and happy showcasing!**

---

This is a proposal for an upcoming event here on Meta. I'd like to get feedback on the tiny details of what you think would be good parameters or if you see flaws or potential improvements.

---

With [4042 questions asked and 3098 answers provided](https://data.stackexchange.com/gamedev/query/edit/1347691) during the past year, we've been able to help a lot of folks!

Likely, some of our users have been able to publish a game, whether it is on the different mobile, desktop or web platforms.

Here, I'm proposing we help those who contributed to the site to showcase their newly published game.

Here are the rules:

- We'd like you to post one answer per game.
- Of course, you will add a link to where you publish your game, but the answer can't be a link only one: please tell us about your game, this is a sales pitch for your game ;)
- You must have received at least 100 reputation on gamedev between December 1st 2019 and today. (Whether it is from questions, answers, bounties, or even if you've edited 50 questions and got rep for it.)
- Your game must have been first published between December 1st 2019 and today. We need to be able to verify this. A published game can be:

  - a game you have made on your own as an indie
  - a game you worked on at a game development studio (yes, you can still be proud of your work in this case)
  - a game you produced during a game jam
  - a game that was released in "beta" or "early access" during the past year, or that was in beta/early access last year and is now out of beta.
- The links you provide must link directly to the distribution platform(s), it must not be a "short link" such as bit.ly, or include some kind of redirection.
- No new answers will be allowed once StackExchange Winterbash 2020 is over.
- As always, the content must

  - be SFW (Safe-For-Work)
  - respect StackExchange [Code of Conduct](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/conduct) and [Acceptable Use Policy](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/legal/acceptable-use-policy), such as (but not limited to):

    - > **No bigotry.**
      > We don’t tolerate any language likely to offend or alienate people based on race, gender, sexual orientation, or religion — and those are just a few examples. Use stated pronouns (when known). When in doubt, don't use language that might offend or alienate.
    - > **No harassment.**
      > This includes, but isn’t limited to: bullying, intimidation, vulgar language, direct or indirect threats, sexually suggestive remarks, patterns of inappropriate social contact, and sustained disruptions of discussion.
    - > **Sexually Explicit Material.** Accounts that use Stack Exchange to post sexually explicit or pornographic material, or links to it, will be suspended.

If you think the content of the game is not safe for everyone, please make sure you add a warning notice to your answer, something like an [ESRB content descriptor](https://www.esrb.org/ratings-guide/).

---

Again, this question is a call for improvements, don't go and post links to your game(s) just yet ;) Wait for the actual showcase to begin with [Winterbash 2020](https://winterbash2020.stackexchange.com/)!

I'll improve this post with proposed changes from the answers here.

Answer (score 3):

The Community Managers discussed this internally (I'm a CM - HI!) - and the main concerns we have are similar to Pikalek's - that we're not promoting anything that is NSFW or otherwise breaks our own [Code of Conduct](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/conduct) or [Acceptable Use Policy](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/legal/acceptable-use-policy).

To quote from these documents:

> **No bigotry.**
> We don’t tolerate any language likely to offend or alienate people based on race, gender, sexual orientation, or religion — and those are just a few examples. Use stated pronouns (when known). When in doubt, don't use language that might offend or alienate.

> **No harassment.**
> This includes, but isn’t limited to: bullying, intimidation, vulgar language, direct or indirect threats, sexually suggestive remarks, patterns of inappropriate social contact, and sustained disruptions of discussion.

> **Sexually Explicit Material.** Accounts that use Stack Exchange to post sexually explicit or pornographic material, or links to it, will be suspended.

If you add rules around this to your guidance, this should keep the event in lines with what we allow here. Game designers who are concerned that their game may come close to crossing a line can indicate their concern in a content warning note in their answer, similar to including an [ESRB content descriptor](https://www.esrb.org/ratings-guide/).

It's important for y'all to realize why, in particular, linking to pornographic content can be a problem - it can cause the site (or even the entire network) to get [delisted from web filtering software](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/364/are-questions-about-adult-web-apps-on-or-off-topic/367#367).

Aside from this, we're really excited to see these sorts of community-centric and community-led events on sites, so please have a ton of fun and let me know if I can help with anything.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I have updated the Question!

Answer (score 1):

Does there need to be some declaimer stating that SE has the finally say regarding what it is willing to promote?

It might be a premature concern & I don't like the idea of place explicit content rating restrictions on the entries, but there's overtly NSFW content on Steam & presumably other platforms as well. Given that Stack Exchange is a business, I could see some potential complications. It might be good to just note that up front.

Comment: Thanks for the question, I'll check with SE what they think about it.

Comment: Could be wise to have this condition in case someone tries to promote a game containing hate speech or similar too.