# Show us your game! - Gamedev's Winterbash 2020 Showcase!

Tags: discussion, event

With [4042 questions asked and 3098 answers provided](https://data.stackexchange.com/gamedev/query/edit/1347691) during the past year, we've been able to help a lot of folks!

Likely, some of our users have been able to publish a game, whether it is on the different mobile, desktop or web platforms.

Here, I'm proposing we help those who contributed to the site to showcase their newly published game.

Here are the rules:

- We'd like you to post one answer per game.
- Of course, you will add a link to where you publish your game, but the answer can't be a link only one: please tell us about your game, this is a sales pitch for your game ;)
- You must have received at least 100 reputation on gamedev between December 1st 2019 and today. (Whether it is from questions, answers, bounties, or even if you've edited 50 questions and got rep for it.)
- Your game must have been first published between December 1st 2019 and today. We need to be able to verify this. A published game can be:

  - a game you have made on your own as an indie
  - a game you worked on at a game development studio (yes, you can still be proud of your work in this case)
  - a game you produced during a game jam
  - a game that was released in "beta" or "early access" during the past year, or that was in beta/early access last year and is now out of beta.
- The links you provide must link directly to the distribution platform(s), it must not be a "short link" such as bit.ly, or include some kind of redirection.
- No new answers will be allowed once StackExchange Winterbash 2020 is over.
- As always, the content must

  - be SFW (Safe-For-Work)
  - respect StackExchange [Code of Conduct](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/conduct) and [Acceptable Use Policy](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/legal/acceptable-use-policy), such as (but not limited to):

    - > **No bigotry.**
      > We don’t tolerate any language likely to offend or alienate people based on race, gender, sexual orientation, or religion — and those are just a few examples. Use stated pronouns (when known). When in doubt, don't use language that might offend or alienate.
    - > **No harassment.**
      > This includes, but isn’t limited to: bullying, intimidation, vulgar language, direct or indirect threats, sexually suggestive remarks, patterns of inappropriate social contact, and sustained disruptions of discussion.
    - > **Sexually Explicit Material.** Accounts that use Stack Exchange to post sexually explicit or pornographic material, or links to it, will be suspended.

If you think the content of the game is not safe for everyone, please make sure you add a warning notice to your answer, something like an [ESRB content descriptor](https://www.esrb.org/ratings-guide/).

Comment: How about ongoing game development? I have been working on my project since 2008(2013) and it is nowhere near final release xD Although it is very playable and has already seen 11 major Alpha releases. GDSE was a great help throughout too :-)

Comment: @Kromster I'm sure we would get nice in-progress games too, but I felt the "released" games would get lost in the "in-progress" games, mainly because "in-progress" would also include "hey look! I have started this Pokémon clone yesterday (oh, and I'll abandon this project in a week or two)" games. Perhaps we could find a way to showcase those as well, as this could help further development of gamedev's users games.

Comment: Thanks for reply! Maybe wip projects will need to have a released playable build. I really want to share mine, but I don't want to be causing any trouble with that. P.S. Maybe seeing the project link in my profile will help to get the state and formulate the rules better. Dunno )

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the submission period has ended. Thanks for participating!

Answer (score 8):

Here's a little toy I built in a weekend for [TOJam](http://www.tojam.ca/default.asp) this year.

The theme was "Together, but Apart" so I wanted to play with mechanics of combining and separating things, which quickly turned into an excuse to play with goopy metaball shaders.

I had this mental image of blobs of liquid that look like glass orbs somehow containing sky, leading to:

## [The Weather Inside](https://dmgregory.itch.io/weather-inside)

(Free on PC, Mac, Android, or play in-browser via WebGL)

[image: Weather Inside Title Screen]

Click on or drag the blobs around to see how they react (especially satisfying on a multi-touch display)

- **Exploration Mode** offers a light puzzle. Experiment to find out how blobs combine to make different kinds of weather. The "Discoveries" list in the ⋮ tab on the left can give you some clues about what to try next.
- **Creative Mode** turns off all the discovery-tracking and "chemical reactions" between blobs, so you can just have fun finger-painting with the sky.

[image: Making blobs of sky]

Thank you to [Zsolt Szanati](https://www.zsoltszanati.com/) for doing sound design for the game, with additional sounds by Mike Koenig via [SoundBible.com](http://soundbible.com/).

Comment: i love this concept!