# Show us your game! - Gamedev's Winter (Summer?) Bash 2021 Showcase!

Tags: discussion, event

It's that time of year again!

With [3355 questions asked and 2783 answers provided](https://data.stackexchange.com/gamedev/revision/1347691/1874273/questions-and-answers-count-over-the-last-year) during the past year, we've been able to help a lot of folks!

Likely, some of our users have been able to publish a game, whether it is on the different mobile, desktop or web platforms.

Here, I'm proposing we help those who contributed to the site to showcase their newly published game.

Here are the rules:

- We'd like you to post one answer per game.
- Of course, you will add a link to where you publish your game, but the answer can't be a link only one: please tell us about your game, this is a sales pitch for your game ;)
- You must have received at least 100 reputation on gamedev between December 1st 2020 and today. (Whether it is from questions, answers, bounties, or even if you've edited 50 questions and got rep for it.)
- Your game must have been first published between December 1st 2020 and today. We need to be able to verify this. A published game can be:

  - a game you have made on your own as an indie
  - a game you worked on at a game development studio (yes, you can still be proud of your work in this case)
  - a game you produced during a game jam
  - a game that was released in "beta" or "early access" during the past year, or that was in beta/early access last year and is now out of beta.
- The links you provide must link directly to the distribution platform(s), it must not be a "short link" such as bit.ly, or include some kind of redirection.
- No new answers will be allowed once StackExchange Winter Bash 2021 is over.
- As always, the content must

  - be SFW (Safe-For-Work)
  - respect StackExchange [Code of Conduct](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/conduct) and [Acceptable Use Policy](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/legal/acceptable-use-policy), such as (but not limited to):

    - > **No bigotry.**
      > We don’t tolerate any language likely to offend or alienate people based on race, gender, sexual orientation, or religion — and those are just a few examples. Use stated pronouns (when known). When in doubt, don't use language that might offend or alienate.
    - > **No harassment.**
      > This includes, but isn’t limited to: bullying, intimidation, vulgar language, direct or indirect threats, sexually suggestive remarks, patterns of inappropriate social contact, and sustained disruptions of discussion.
    - > **Sexually Explicit Material.** Accounts that use Stack Exchange to post sexually explicit or pornographic material, or links to it, will be suspended.

If you think the content of the game is not safe for everyone, please make sure you add a warning notice to your answer, something like an [ESRB content descriptor](https://www.esrb.org/ratings-guide/).

Comment: The hat season is gone, and so this event is concluded. Thanks all for your participation!

Answer (score 4):

My name is Steven, I'm a hobbyist artist and I've been programming as proffession for 4 years.
Begin 2021 I've released a Metroidvania project called HertenHeld.

https://ppowersteef.itch.io/hertenheld

[image]

*(This was published as Beta since July 2019, and released in feb 2021, so it's technically just outside the "published as Beta/early access since past year" criteria. Hopefully that requirement isn't too strict)*

It's a short game where you play as a huntress to save her pet deer from a big wolf. 
Similair as in Metroidvanias, you explore a forest to find upgrades that helps you to progress in new areas.

My drawing experience helped me to make my own assets, it's fun to see your creations coming alive this way.

It's a project that I've been working on since 2017. And it was the first time I tried out a platformer and GameMaker Studio 2. 
I love the design of Metroidvanias and I've wanted to create one myself, but a lot of them have so much content that it felt overwhelming for a solo developer, until I came accross an indie metroidvania series called Momodora, and that helped me to see Metroidvanias in a smaller indie scale.

The development has been quite the journey with ups and downs. As this was only my second game I've been working on. It was a test on my dedication, and there felt a great relief once the project was finally done. Even though I started to miss working on the project as well, haha.

I've visited this site a lot to search for GameMaker questions and helped similair juniors with problems I've faced as well. I've enjoyed gaining experience in GameMaker Studio 2 this way.

Comment: Nice! Thanks for sharing this with us :)

Answer (score 4):

Carrying on my [tradition from last year](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2870/39518), let me tell you about the game I made in a weekend for [TOJam](http://www.tojam.ca/default.asp) this year!

[image: that's my jam title screen & track select]

["that's my jam!"](https://dmgregory.itch.io/thats-my-jam) is a freestyling rhythm game. That means you're scored for pressing buttons to the beat, but you get to choose what buttons to press.

You can use the directional arrows / WASD / DPAD / analog stick to step to the left/right/upstage/downstage, and QZEC / UJIK / face buttons / bumpers and triggers to swing your left & right arms out or up.

The game procedurally animates the dancers to follow your moves.

[image: Dancing example]

[image: Scoring example]

Thanks to David Vitas and James Stajov for providing the game's music tracks, Kenney.nl for the character assets, mukets for the cassette tape model, and Essqué Productions for the Neon 80s font.

[Get it free from itch.io here](https://dmgregory.itch.io/thats-my-jam), and let me know what you think!