# Show us your [in-development] game! - Gamedev's Winter/Summer Bash 2022 Showcase!

Tags: discussion, event

It's that time of year again!

With [2447 questions asked and 1889 answers provided](https://data.stackexchange.com/gamedev/revision/1347691/2054031/questions-and-answers-count-over-the-last-year) during the past year, we've been able to help a lot of folks!

Likely, some of our users have been able to publish a game, whether it is on the different mobile, desktop or web platforms, while others have been able make progress toward that goal!

Here, we're proposing to help gamedev community members who contributed to the site by showcasing their their latest release, or the progress they've made over the past year.

Here are the rules:

- We'd like you to post one answer per game.
- You must be a member of the GameDev.StackExchange community.
- If you've published your game:

  - You can add a link to where you publish your game, but the answer can't be a link only one: please tell us about your game, this is a sales pitch for your game ;)
  - Your game must have been first published between December 1st 2021 and today. We need to be able to verify this. A published game can be:

    - a game you have made on your own as an indie
    - a game you worked on at a game development studio (yes, you can still be proud of your work in this case)
    - a game you produced during a game jam
    - a game that was released in "beta" or "early access" during the past year, or that was in beta/early access last year and is now out of beta.
- If you want to show your progress instead, you can share with us

  - What's the most recent feature you've got in?
  - What are you the most proud of so far?
  - What's been the hardest part to do so far, why, and how did you managed to get over it?
  - What part do you think will be the hardest to complete in the near future?
  - What's a cool trick or solution you found that others might find useful?
- The links you provide must link directly to the distribution platform(s), it must not be a "short link" such as bit.ly, or include some kind of redirection.
- No new answers will be allowed once StackExchange Winter Bash 2022 is over.
- As always, the content must

  - be SFW (Safe-For-Work); if you think the content of the game is not safe for everyone, please make sure you add a warning notice to your answer, something like an [ESRB content descriptor](https://www.esrb.org/ratings-guide/).
  - respect StackExchange [Code of Conduct](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/conduct) and [Acceptable Use Policy](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/legal/acceptable-use-policy), such as (but not limited to):

    - > **No bigotry.**
      > We don’t tolerate any language likely to offend or alienate people based on race, gender, sexual orientation, or religion — and those are just a few examples. Use stated pronouns (when known). When in doubt, don't use language that might offend or alienate.
    - > **No harassment.**
      > This includes, but isn’t limited to: bullying, intimidation, vulgar language, direct or indirect threats, sexually suggestive remarks, patterns of inappropriate social contact, and sustained disruptions of discussion.
    - > **Sexually Explicit Material.** Accounts that use Stack Exchange to post sexually explicit or pornographic material, or links to it, will be suspended.

---

You may have noticed that we've merged both [Show us your in-development game!](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2951/show-us-your-in-development-game-gamdevs-septemberbash-2022-showcase) and [Show us your game!](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2927/show-us-your-game-gamedevs-winter-summer-bash-2021-showcase) events. We think will allow more users to post about their game, and make this event much more interesting!

Comment: The event is now closed, see you next year!

Comment: I'm sad I've missed it. I would have shown my gamedev progress )